# How the set is compact?

Tags: general-topology

R with usual topology. The set 
  
    K
    n
  
  =
  [
  0
  ,
  1
  −
  1
  
    /
  
  n
  ]
  where n belongs to N.
How it is compact? and why its union is not compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is compact because it is closed and bounded. But the union of these K(n) is [0, 1) is not compact because it is not closed for 1 is a limit point of this union but not belong to it.

Comment: Great. very useful answer. Thank you.